# Using a certificate from Keychain in a Mac application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, certificate, keychain

I am trying to build a mini-application to codesign one Mac OS X application with `codesign` utility and my developer certificate in keychain. To do that I use `NSTask`, like that :

```
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/codesign"];
// ...
NSString *certificateName = @"\"3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Firstname Lastname\"";
NSString *appName = @"\"/path/to/My App.app\"";
NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-s", certificateName, appName, nil];
// ...
[task launch];
```

I use a `NSPipe` to catch the output and I got this error message : `no identity found`...
But if I launch this command manually via Terminal, the application is well signed (so it's not a problem of certificate badly installed, etc).

I think issue comes because my application can't access the certificate in keychain (but me I can via Terminal).

Does someone already experienced this problem ?

Thanks in advance, Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not embed additional quotation marks in the arguments to `NSTask`:

```
NSString *certificateName = @"3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Firstname Lastname";
NSString *appName = @"/path/to/My App.app";
```

Spaces in the arguments are handled automatically, and do not require quotation marks.

Comment: Oh my... You're right ! I was sure to have tested this. Shame on me :s Thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: Ah, I remember my error... Before I tried without additional quotation marks but I forgotten a space between `3rd Party Mac Developer Application:` and `Firstname Lastname`, so the same message `no identity found` appears (but not for the same reason). A stupid issue, quickly solved thanks to you Martin.